# Ajax requests to audio files in Safari don't work when appcache is enabled

Tags: html, safari, xmlhttprequest, web-audio-api

I use application cache manifest to cache media contents of a web game, then in the game I use the Web Audio API to play some sounds.

This works on Chrome, and the first time to load on Safari. But subsequently it will fail on Safari because the XHR request for the audio files actually returns an empty string.

The same happen to Mobile Safari as well.

Anyone has any idea why this happens? Any possible workaround while keeping the app cache for audio?

Comment: Um, this should work - do you have those files listed in the manifest?

Comment: @cwilso yes. In fact, if I don't list them, thereby disabling the cache for them, the audio will work.